# Where Do Whores Go?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Song Of Ice And Fire*, Tyrion Lannister wanders Valyria in search of his lost love, Tysha.

Heavy spoiler from *A Storm of Swords* part 2, you have been warned.

> When Tyrion kills Tywin, Tywin tells Tyrion to look for Tysha, "Wherever whores go."

Therefore Tyrion asks most people he meets, "Where do whores go?"

Where *do* they go?

Comment: Well, so we have here a legitimate question on where to find whores

Comment: Read the Arya chapters in Braavos, and see what you think of the whores she meets. One of them is interesting.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking where Tysha is? Are you asking where there's the highest concentration of whores? Are you asking if there's a Dosh Khaleen equivalent for whores? Is there a training camp for whores?

Comment: @Mooz he's asking where's the place referenced by Tywin

Comment: Brothels, I guess?

Comment: If you ask Meat Loaf, _good girls go to Heaven; bad girls go everywhere_, so I guess ***everywhere***.

Comment: Some part of me feels like there's a farm joke here, much like with dead pets...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of [Midian, where the monsters live.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightbreed)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Where do whores go? Very well thank you. Ok, that doesn't  quite work does it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### We don't know.

Someone asked GRRM in a video interview, but he ain't saying. From [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2uf9kc/spoilers_all_so_last_week_i_got_to_talk_to_grrm/):

> "Hi George! I have a couple of questions. First of all, do we ever find out where do whores go?"
>
> "Well..." he said, uncertain and hesitant to answer the question.
>
> "Oh, I'm not really asking for the story, I just want to go there."
>
> Everyone laughed, including Gurm *[sic]*, and through his high-pitched giggles he uttered a "Yes."
>
> "Really? Oh, that's so cool, thanks!"

Naturally, the internet is rife with speculation, and theories abound.

- Reddit threads: [one](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/28akp1/spoilers_all_finally_where_do_whores_go/), [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/3cwrzk/spoilers_all_where_do_whores_go/)
- aWoIaF forums: [one](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/73546-an-answer-to-where-do-whores-go-tysha-littlefinger-tyrion/), [two](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/124356-where-do-whores-go/)
- Quora: [one](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-answer-to-Tyrions-oft-repeated-question-Where-do-whores-go)

That should give you a good deal of reading material if it's theories and rumours you're looking for. But as far as hard facts go, we won't know until book 6 comes out, if then.

Answer (score 8):

This is likely a rhetorical statement, indicating that Tywin neither knows nor cares where she ended up. Given Tywin's disdain for members of the oldest profession, he's hardly likely to have kept track of someone he used purely as an educational tool for his son.

Tyrion's repetition of the question to others is an in-joke to himself, a bleak reflection assisted by alcohol and his fugue state.